# How should I loop an INSERT INTO statement for SQL on R?

Tags: r

```
    query <- paste0("INSERT INTO [MASTER] ([name], [code], [type]) VALUES(",
                   "'",data$name,"', ", "'",data$code,"', ","'",data$type,"')")
query_execute <- DBI:dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = query)
```

So I have a dataframe called data, with various values in name, code and type columns.

How should I config my for loops so that it can go through from row 1 to the end and insert the data on each row separately?

Asking as I can't just insert the entire dataframe using this method, I get

```
 Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=27].
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the number of rows, then filter the table at each loop:

```
for (i in nrow(data)){
  query <- paste0("INSERT INTO [MASTER] ([name], [code], [type]) VALUES(",
               "'", data[i, ]$name, "', ", "'", data[i, ]$code, "', ","'",data[i, ]$type,"')")
  query_execute <- DBI:dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = query)
}
```

Take note that you need to include the comma "," inside the square brackets after the index so that it would be filtered row-wise and not column-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You may set up a simple `for` loop with `DBI::dbSendQuery`.

```
for (q in query) {
  DBI::dbSendQuery(conn = con, statement = q)
}
```

Comment: Note that this kind of loops might result in data inconsistency when things crash halfway the loop (only half the inserts are executed). It might be worth looking int transaction to ensure everything happens as expected. You might also want to have a look at `dbWriteTable`